# FOS UserBundle server error when logout link hit

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am new to the FriendsOfSymfony UserBundle and everything has been going well until I try to have a user logout.  The login works perfectly and I am using the basic configuration that I have seen on many sites. I only have 2 users that need to login. The problem occurs when the user clicks on the logout URL.  In this case /logout.  I receve a generic server error in the browser and the error_log shows "Premature end of script headers: app_dev.php".  If I hit refresh on the error page it goes back to my home page and I am logged out successfully.

Here is my firewall section in security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout: true
        anonymous: true
```

Here is the access_control section of security.yml:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel:https }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/logout, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Here is the fos_user section in config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Wielding\BassBundle\Entity\User
```

I am generating the logout url in my twig form with:

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">logout</a>
```

If I am not logged into the site and I go manually to the logout url I get redirected back to the default index page without any error.  If I am logged in and manually type in the logout url I get the server error.  I have tried so many variations of config changes I can't even list them here.  They all failed.

I even tried to write my own logout by invalidating the session in the controller and that generates the same error.

My only clue so far is an entry in dev.log:

```
[2013-07-27 14:51:26] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: SessionHandler::write(): Parent session handler is not open in /home/dev2/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 407" at /home/dev2/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 407 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException: Warning: SessionHandler::write(): Parent session handler is not open in /home/dev2/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 407 at /home/dev2/app/cache/dev/classes.php:407)"} []
```

Searching on this initially indicated that this was not something to worry about but I am out of other ideas.  This is my final task in getting security working and its freaking me out.

I will gladly provide any other information needed to help solve this really annoying problem.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What's your version of php ?

Comment: I am running 5.4.4-14+deb7u2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's error of PHP. You need to upgrade php to minium 5.4.11.

Reference:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5868

Comment: I decided to push it to my production box since it is not a critical error and oddly it seems to work there.  The servers should be identical except for the fact that the production server is serving some other sites.  The PHP versions match at 5.4.4-14+deb7u2.

Comment: Update to 5.4.11 minimum

Comment: Thanks, I will look into updating to 5.4.11.  I am not sure what the best way to do that is since I use webmin/virtualmin on my servers and they install php from the standard debian repo.

Comment: For reference, until I can figure out the best way to upgrade PHP on my servers adding

    `invalidate_session: false`

to the logout section of my security.yml prevents the error